# Script for correcting linux filenames on windows and vice versa?

Tags: windows, linux, encoding, filenames, command-line-interface

As far as I know, Unix-like systems use UTF-8 for encoding filenames, while Windows system use their own Windows single-byte encodings.

I am working with archives with japanese filenames in them quite oftenly. When I open such archive created in Windows, japanese letters are dead, because filename encoding is incorrect.

Same thing happens, when I create archive in my Linux and then someone opens it under Windows.

So, I have thought that this should be quite common problem, and, because filenames are recoverable there must already exist correcting .sh script for linux and .bat script for Windows.

But after googling for quite a long time I still have not found anything.
Is there such scripts at all? If not, what difficultuies may have stopped people from creating them?

**Update**
I would be happy with a solution that works for most Linux systems and most Windows systems.

Comment: The problem space is quite a lot more complex than that.  There are multiple Linux file systems, some of which allow the operator to specify a local file name character set, and multiple Windows file systems with various more or less outlandish antipatterns from Redmond (they like to call them "features").  The archive container should have a way to specify the coding system of file names, but you are not saying which sort of archive you are using.  Are you talking about `zip` files?

Comment: I have same problems with both zip and rar files.

Comment: It would probably be easier to do this from an executable than from a script.  Provided the archiving tools are actually preserving the file name information (which might not be the case!) it shouldn't be difficult.  The only other thing I'm not sure about is whether the encoding will be predictable or whether the code or the user would have to try to figure out the appropriate encoding in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your input. Case indeed looks quite complex for simple bash script, I'll need to use programming language.

I don't see anything like "close question" button, so I'll use this answer to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses the two byte encoding UTF-16. Your problem is most likely that you are using single byte ANSI versions of whatever archive tool you are using.

Until you give more details of the code and tools you are using it's hard to give specific advice. However, the are no limitations on using the full range of Unicode characters in modern Windows file systems.

Comment: winrar on windows, gnome file roller on linux

Comment: this seems like a superuser question to me, I don't think there is any code is there?

Comment: I wanted .sh and .bat scripts to fix names after unpacking, or some guides where to start with writing them. But everybody just started asking question what software I'm using.

Comment: the filenames should not be mangled at all. And I had to correct your misinformation about Windows storing filenames with a single byte encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [convmv tool](http://www.faqforge.com/linux/convert-the-charset-of-file-names-from-iso-8859-15-to-utf8/) available for Unix systems